# Move selected items to top of listbox

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am really going crazy over finding solution for showing selected items in listbox at top.
I am using knockout here to bind my list box. The listbox is binded as below in my view

```
<select id ="multiAltVersion" multiple="multiple"  data-bind="options:  $root.editOnlyAlternativeVersions,  optionsText: 'PlatformVersionName',optionsValue: 'Id',selectedOptions:  $root.copiedAltVersion, chosen: true  "> </select>
```

I call my WCF service to fill the listbox.

```
    function loadVersionListByProductType(prodtype) {
        var input =
        {
            ProductType: prodtype

        };


        $.ajax({
            url: "../RestService/Test/ReturnData",
            type: "PUT",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            processData: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(input),
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            },
            success: function (allData) {
                var mappedVersionListByProdType = $.map(allData, function (item) {

                    return new productVersionListByProductType(item);
                });
                self.editOnlyAlternativeVersions(mappedVersionListByProdType);


            }

        });

    }
```

When the data is returned from WCF service it returns data in descending order. But i want to show selected at top and then sort the list in descending manner. I get list of items from another service and selected items from another service. Does it make sense? How can i achieve it using Jquery?

Comment: Why are you using a `PUT` to `GET` data?

Comment: On your question, you could use a computed property to return an array with the selected item at the top.

Comment: @MattBurland i use to send data in json format. But is this relevant to question?

Comment: @MattBurland can you give me example of how to do it with computed observable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sorting functionality](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) in Knockout when you download the data:

```
editOnlyAlternativeVersions.sort(function(left, right)
{
    return left.selected == right.selected ? 
        // Selected is equal, so sort on name
        left.name == right.name ? 0 : (left.name < right.name ? -1 : 1) : (left.selected < right.selected ? -1 : 1)
})
```

Comment: i think i cant use this method because i get list in one observable array and selected item in other observable. Dont know how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example using computed observables (untested and unoptimized):

```
var myViewModel = function() {
   var options = ko.observableArray(["option1","option2","option3"]);
   var selected = ko.observable(options[2]);

   var sortedOptions = ko.computed(function() {
       var sorted = [];
       sorted.push(selected());
       for (var i=0; i < options().length; i++) {
           if(options()[i]!=selected()) {
              sorted.push(options()[i]);
           }
       }
       return sorted;
   });
}
```

Then bind to `sortedOptions` and it should be in the order:

```
option3, option1, option2
```

Selecting a new option will force it to recalculate as will adding new options to the `options` array.

Comment: In my variable options i get array as following productVersionListByProductType {Id: function, Name: function, PlatformVersionName: function, ProductEntityId: function, CompatibilityLevel: function}.  In my selected variable i get data as [49, 43].  So i changed the condition to if(options()[i].Id()!=selected()).  Still it doesnt work.

Comment: Also this sortedOptions is a html propery for listbox?

Comment: Is it possible to post a fiddle?

Comment: @AshReva: `sortedOptions` is what you'll bind to, as in `options:  sortedOptions`

Comment: @AshReva: Since you have an array of selected items, you will need to first iterate through the selected items and add them to `sorted`, then you will need to iterate through the rest of the options skipping those that have already been added.

Comment: @AshReva: And yes, you could post a fiddle.

Comment: no i meant can you post the fiddle? I am not so comfortable with knockout yet

Comment: @AshReva: Why? It would make a lot more sense for you to post your problem. You've given very little information (for example, what does your view model look like?) which is why you are only getting very general answers.

Comment: can you do something in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kKNtv/224/ Although my view model is bit different but i will try when you are able to do in fiddle i mentioned